# Tring to repeat the binary adder i made, but i get errors like indents and invalid syntax. Anyone see problems related to the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("Input a binary number")

num1 = int(input() , 2)

print ("again prease")

num2 = int(input() , 2)

answer = num1 + num2

binaryanswer = bin(answer)[2:]

print ("That's " ,binaryanswer, " In behhieerryy")

input ("Press enter to end Program")          

again = raw_input

if again == 'Y':
    print("AGAAAINN!!")
    return

else:
    break
```

Everythin does it's job, but i just can get the program to repeat itself.

Answer (score 2):

`return` doest mean it will start again. There is nothing in your program that will cause it to repeat. Put it in a function and if the user presses 'Y' then call the function again.

```
while 1:
    print ("Input a binary number")

    num1 = int(input() , 2)

    print ("again please")

    num2 = int(input() , 2)

    answer = num1 + num2

    binaryanswer = bin(answer)[2:]

    print ("That's " ,binaryanswer, " In behhieerryy")

    again = input ("Press enter to end Program")          



    if again != 'Y':
        break

    print("AGAAAINN!!")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `while (running)` loop? And also you are using `else: break`. You should probably use `else: return` there

Comment: repeating a function by recursively calling it is bad practice. If the user enters Y five hundred times, you'll get a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but try this:

```
while True:
    print ("Input a binary number")
    num1 = int(input() , 2)
    print ("again prease")
    num2 = int(input() , 2)
    answer = num1 + num2
    binaryanswer = bin(answer)[2:]
    print ("That's " ,binaryanswer, " In behhieerryy")
    again = input("Press Y to try again or enter to end Program") 
    if again == 'Y':
        print("AGAAAINN!!")
    else:
        break
```